# How to include a PDF image into a PDFLaTeX document

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdfpages

I am generating a PDF file using `pdflatex` and need to include another PDF file. The reason is that I have a `graphMl` file which I exported from *yEd* graph editor to a PDF file, named `sample.pdf`. The TeX code to be compiled with `pdflatex` is given below. I need to include that file at the start of the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

 [% FOREACH st IN Service %]
   Name,Id:
  [% st.Id %], [% st.Name %]

   des:
  [% st.Description %]

  Customers:
 [% FOREACH softservice IN st.Customers %]
  [% FOREACH swid IN softservice.SW %]
 [% swid.Service %] 
 [% FOREACH st IN Service %][% IF swid.Service == st.Id %]
    ([% st.Name %]) 

  [% END %] [% END %][% END %][% END %]

  Suppliers:

  [% FOREACH shservice IN st.Suppliers %]
   [% FOREACH sw IN shservice.SW %][% sw.Service %]
    [% FOREACH st IN Service %][% IF sw.Service == st.Id %]([% st.Name %]) 
    [% END %][% END %][% END %]

  [% FOREACH hw IN shservice.HW %][% hw.Type %][% hw.Nr %][% END %]
  [% END %]
  \newpage
  [% END %]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious: That code looks badly broken and doesn't make much sense (most of it is commented out). Is yEd _that_ bad?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Have a look at the [`pdfpages` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
   \includepdf[<options>]{<file>}

   Your Text
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
Miguel suggested `graphicx` to include a graphic which is correct, the difference between `graphicx` and `pdfpages` is that `graphicx` puts the PDF as a graphic on a text page (maybe inside a `{figure}` float environment, whereas `pdfpages` inserst the pages of a given PDF between the pages of your document.

Comment: I have small problem when I try to insert external pdf image into my pdflatex document on page 13 and one more image on page 14, I am not able to insert external pdf images on specific page number.my problem is I need to insert exteranl pdf images on bottom side of page 13 and page 14. Can you help me with that.I tried to insert but it inserting on starting page of latex generated pdf.

Comment: @pavani: I’m not sure if I understood you right (please add a new MWE to your question showing the problem) … If you want to include the external PDF as _part_ of a LaTeX-page use `\includegraphics` instead of `\pdfpages`

Comment: If I want to insert vector graphics in a larger latex document is it better to use svg images or pdf images?

Comment: @skan: only PDF is supported natively and furthermore SVG is mir for web than print. Thus I'd use a PDF file ...

Comment: If I use a software such as inkscape to create a vector graphic and I export it as pdf...  Will the result still be a vector graphic (converted to pdf graphic)? Or is better if I create a svg?

Comment: Degens on how you export the PDF, but in general Inkscape should export as vectors. You can test it by zooming in as much as possible if all lines/edges are still sharp it is a vector graphic … / Another reason for PDF ist that SVG doesn’t support CMYK (only RGB) color space, while CMYK is required for (professional) printing. But I’m not sure about the status of Inkscape’s CMYK support, seems like one needs an [extension to export CMYK PDFs](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExportPDFCMYK).

Answer (score 150):

Loading the `graphicx` package in the preamble it is possible to import PDF images in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[<options>]{filename.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here `<options>` can be e.g. `width=<width>`, `height=<height` or `page=<page number>`. See the [*Graphics Guide*](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I have small problem when I try to insert external pdf image into my pdflatex document on page 13 and one more image on page 14, I am not able to insert external pdf images on specific page number.my problem is I need to insert exteranl pdf images on bottom side of page 13 and page 14. Can you help me with that.I tried to insert but it inserting on starting page of latex generated pdf.

Comment: To include a figure in the bottom of the page you could use a figure environment in the document where you want to have the figure: \begin{figure}[b]\includegraphics[<options>]{filename.pdf}
\end{figure} . For more information about positioning of figures see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Floats

Comment: +1 This is the best answer here! Includegraphics much better to use than a new command.

Comment: Great solution. I add some details that I got stuck with. The latex command will not compile the code with a pdf image. However, pdflatex and xelatex will.

Comment: This is the correct and most useful answer to the question.

Comment: Will they be imported as vector graphic or will they be rasterized by the graphicx package?

Comment: The graphicx package supports importing PDFs in both vector graphics and raster images formats.

Comment: Can I include multiple pages at one go using `includegraphics`?

Comment: It seems that the solution by `\usepackage{graphicx}` can not work in https://www.overleaf.com/project/. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I use the package epstopdf to insert graphic in format different than those that Latex commonly processes. It works for .pdf, .tiff, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[<options>]{filename.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this does not work for XeTeX