# From LibreOffice Calc to LaTeX - exporting tables and graphs

Tags: libre-office

Is there any easy way to export/convert LibreOffice tables & graphs to LaTeX format?

**EDIT**

[this website](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables) allows you to paste the data and generates LaTeX formatted tables.

**CALC LOOKS LIKE THIS:**

[image]

Comment: Also the graphics package could be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39446/101651.

Comment: The solution, in my option, is to export the pdf from Calc and then include it in your LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`, as indicated in the answer I linked before. You can set the `width=<width>` and/or the `height=<height` to fit it into your LaTeX document. Look at the `graphics` or `graphicx` package documentation: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx.

Comment: You can crop your `pdf` with the `trim` option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57420/101651

Comment: I think there's no problem, then, there is also the option `page` where you can choose the page to include with the command

Comment: I have no idea about transferring the graphs, but pasting data tables into LyX (which produces LaTeX) is easy. Just copy the cells, go to LyX > Insert > Table and choose the appropriate number of rows and cells (it must match what you copied in LibreOffice Calc). Then press "OK". Then select the upper-left cell of the table, and press ctrl+shift+v.

Comment: @HernanMiraola no, it is desktop software so it would provide an offline solution. But the end result would be about the same I think.

Comment: Not with pdfpages, with graphicx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[page=1,trim=10 400 0 100, clip, width=\linewidth]{yourpdf.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Where `yourpdf.pdf` is a file with this two pages:

[image]

[image]

And the result of my MWE is:

[image]

The values to use in the `trim` option depend on your document and images, from the package documentation:

> **trim** Similar to viewport, but here the four lengths specify the amount
>   to remove or add to each side. trim= 1 2 3 4 `crops' the
>   picture by 1bp at the left, 2bp at the bottom, 3bp on the
>   right and 4bp at the top.

With some trial & errors, you can find them easily.