# How should this tikz code generated from Inkscape be adjusted?

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

The following tikz code is what I obtained from Inkscape (see the svg-file in https://github.com/lichengzhang1/myfig/blob/main/bipa32.svg), but when I run it, it doesn't give me the desired result. Is there a missing package? How should I adjust it?

The image in Inkscape likes this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{c800000}{RGB}{128,0,0}


\def \globalscale {1.000000}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, yscale=\globalscale,xscale=\globalscale, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (12.4688,39.7316) --
    (8.0664,39.7316) -- (4.2543,41.9328) -- (2.0531,45.7449) -- (2.0531,50.1469)
    -- (4.2543,53.9594) -- (8.0664,56.1602) -- (12.4688,56.1602) --
    (16.2809,53.9594) -- (18.4820,50.1469) -- (18.4820,45.7449) --
    (16.2809,41.9328) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (12.6730,30.2883) .. controls
    (12.6730, 30.3984) and (12.5840, 30.4875) .. (12.4738, 30.4875) .. controls
    (12.3641, 30.4875) and (12.2746, 30.3984) .. (12.2746, 30.2883) .. controls
    (12.2746, 30.1781) and (12.3641, 30.0891) .. (12.4738, 30.0891) .. controls
    (12.5840, 30.0891) and (12.6730, 30.1781) .. (12.6730, 30.2883) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (8.2605,30.2883) .. controls
    (8.2605, 30.3984) and (8.1711, 30.4875) .. (8.0613, 30.4875) .. controls
    (7.9512, 30.4875) and (7.8621, 30.3984) .. (7.8621, 30.2883) .. controls
    (7.8621, 30.1781) and (7.9512, 30.0891) .. (8.0613, 30.0891) .. controls
    (8.1711, 30.0891) and (8.2605, 30.1781) .. (8.2605, 30.2883) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (4.4391,28.0820) .. controls
    (4.4391, 28.1922) and (4.3496, 28.2812) .. (4.2398, 28.2812) .. controls
    (4.1297, 28.2812) and (4.0406, 28.1922) .. (4.0406, 28.0820) .. controls
    (4.0406, 27.9719) and (4.1297, 27.8828) .. (4.2398, 27.8828) .. controls
    (4.3496, 27.8828) and (4.4391, 27.9719) .. (4.4391, 28.0820) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (2.2328,24.2605) .. controls
    (2.2328, 24.3703) and (2.1434, 24.4598) .. (2.0332, 24.4598) .. controls
    (1.9234, 24.4598) and (1.8340, 24.3703) .. (1.8340, 24.2605) .. controls
    (1.8340, 24.1504) and (1.9234, 24.0613) .. (2.0332, 24.0613) .. controls
    (2.1434, 24.0613) and (2.2328, 24.1504) .. (2.2328, 24.2605) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (2.2328,19.8477) .. controls
    (2.2328, 19.9578) and (2.1434, 20.0469) .. (2.0332, 20.0469) .. controls
    (1.9234, 20.0469) and (1.8340, 19.9578) .. (1.8340, 19.8477) .. controls
    (1.8340, 19.7375) and (1.9234, 19.6484) .. (2.0332, 19.6484) .. controls
    (2.1434, 19.6484) and (2.2328, 19.7375) .. (2.2328, 19.8477) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (4.4391,16.0262) .. controls
    (4.4391, 16.1363) and (4.3496, 16.2254) .. (4.2398, 16.2254) .. controls
    (4.1297, 16.2254) and (4.0406, 16.1363) .. (4.0406, 16.0262) .. controls
    (4.0406, 15.9160) and (4.1297, 15.8270) .. (4.2398, 15.8270) .. controls
    (4.3496, 15.8270) and (4.4391, 15.9160) .. (4.4391, 16.0262) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (8.2605,13.8199) .. controls
    (8.2605, 13.9301) and (8.1711, 14.0191) .. (8.0613, 14.0191) .. controls
    (7.9512, 14.0191) and (7.8621, 13.9301) .. (7.8621, 13.8199) .. controls
    (7.8621, 13.7098) and (7.9512, 13.6207) .. (8.0613, 13.6207) .. controls
    (8.1711, 13.6207) and (8.2605, 13.7098) .. (8.2605, 13.8199) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (12.6730,13.8199) .. controls
    (12.6730, 13.9301) and (12.5840, 14.0191) .. (12.4738, 14.0191) .. controls
    (12.3641, 14.0191) and (12.2746, 13.9301) .. (12.2746, 13.8199) .. controls
    (12.2746, 13.7098) and (12.3641, 13.6207) .. (12.4738, 13.6207) .. controls
    (12.5840, 13.6207) and (12.6730, 13.7098) .. (12.6730, 13.8199) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (16.4945,16.0262) .. controls
    (16.4945, 16.1363) and (16.4055, 16.2254) .. (16.2953, 16.2254) .. controls
    (16.1855, 16.2254) and (16.0961, 16.1363) .. (16.0961, 16.0262) .. controls
    (16.0961, 15.9160) and (16.1855, 15.8270) .. (16.2953, 15.8270) .. controls
    (16.4055, 15.8270) and (16.4945, 15.9160) .. (16.4945, 16.0262) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (18.7012,19.8477) .. controls
    (18.7012, 19.9578) and (18.6117, 20.0469) .. (18.5020, 20.0469) .. controls
    (18.3918, 20.0469) and (18.3023, 19.9578) .. (18.3023, 19.8477) .. controls
    (18.3023, 19.7375) and (18.3918, 19.6484) .. (18.5020, 19.6484) .. controls
    (18.6117, 19.6484) and (18.7012, 19.7375) .. (18.7012, 19.8477) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (18.7012,24.2605) .. controls
    (18.7012, 24.3703) and (18.6117, 24.4598) .. (18.5020, 24.4598) .. controls
    (18.3918, 24.4598) and (18.3023, 24.3703) .. (18.3023, 24.2605) .. controls
    (18.3023, 24.1504) and (18.3918, 24.0613) .. (18.5020, 24.0613) .. controls
    (18.6117, 24.0613) and (18.7012, 24.1504) .. (18.7012, 24.2605) -- cycle;



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (11.3680,43.8387) --
    (9.1672,43.8387) -- (7.2609,44.9395) -- (6.1605,46.8453) -- (6.1605,49.0465)
    -- (7.2609,50.9527) -- (9.1672,52.0531) -- (11.3680,52.0531) --
    (13.2742,50.9527) -- (14.3746,49.0465) -- (14.3746,46.8453) --
    (13.2742,44.9395) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (11.5727,26.1812) .. controls
    (11.5727, 26.2910) and (11.4836, 26.3805) .. (11.3734, 26.3805) .. controls
    (11.2633, 26.3805) and (11.1742, 26.2910) .. (11.1742, 26.1812) .. controls
    (11.1742, 26.0711) and (11.2633, 25.9820) .. (11.3734, 25.9820) .. controls
    (11.4836, 25.9820) and (11.5727, 26.0711) .. (11.5727, 26.1812) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (9.3609,26.1812) .. controls
    (9.3609, 26.2910) and (9.2719, 26.3805) .. (9.1617, 26.3805) .. controls
    (9.0516, 26.3805) and (8.9625, 26.2910) .. (8.9625, 26.1812) .. controls
    (8.9625, 26.0711) and (9.0516, 25.9820) .. (9.1617, 25.9820) .. controls
    (9.2719, 25.9820) and (9.3609, 26.0711) .. (9.3609, 26.1812) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (7.4457,25.0754) .. controls
    (7.4457, 25.1855) and (7.3563, 25.2746) .. (7.2465, 25.2746) .. controls
    (7.1363, 25.2746) and (7.0473, 25.1855) .. (7.0473, 25.0754) .. controls
    (7.0473, 24.9652) and (7.1363, 24.8762) .. (7.2465, 24.8762) .. controls
    (7.3563, 24.8762) and (7.4457, 24.9652) .. (7.4457, 25.0754) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (6.3398,23.1598) .. controls
    (6.3398, 23.2699) and (6.2504, 23.3594) .. (6.1406, 23.3594) .. controls
    (6.0305, 23.3594) and (5.9414, 23.2699) .. (5.9414, 23.1598) .. controls
    (5.9414, 23.0500) and (6.0305, 22.9605) .. (6.1406, 22.9605) .. controls
    (6.2504, 22.9605) and (6.3398, 23.0500) .. (6.3398, 23.1598) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (6.3398,20.9484) .. controls
    (6.3398, 21.0582) and (6.2504, 21.1477) .. (6.1406, 21.1477) .. controls
    (6.0305, 21.1477) and (5.9414, 21.0582) .. (5.9414, 20.9484) .. controls
    (5.9414, 20.8383) and (6.0305, 20.7488) .. (6.1406, 20.7488) .. controls
    (6.2504, 20.7488) and (6.3398, 20.8383) .. (6.3398, 20.9484) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (7.4457,19.0328) .. controls
    (7.4457, 19.1430) and (7.3563, 19.2320) .. (7.2465, 19.2320) .. controls
    (7.1363, 19.2320) and (7.0473, 19.1430) .. (7.0473, 19.0328) .. controls
    (7.0473, 18.9227) and (7.1363, 18.8336) .. (7.2465, 18.8336) .. controls
    (7.3563, 18.8336) and (7.4457, 18.9227) .. (7.4457, 19.0328) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (9.3609,17.9270) .. controls
    (9.3609, 18.0371) and (9.2719, 18.1262) .. (9.1617, 18.1262) .. controls
    (9.0516, 18.1262) and (8.9625, 18.0371) .. (8.9625, 17.9270) .. controls
    (8.9625, 17.8168) and (9.0516, 17.7277) .. (9.1617, 17.7277) .. controls
    (9.2719, 17.7277) and (9.3609, 17.8168) .. (9.3609, 17.9270) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (11.5727,17.9270) .. controls
    (11.5727, 18.0371) and (11.4836, 18.1262) .. (11.3734, 18.1262) .. controls
    (11.2633, 18.1262) and (11.1742, 18.0371) .. (11.1742, 17.9270) .. controls
    (11.1742, 17.8168) and (11.2633, 17.7277) .. (11.3734, 17.7277) .. controls
    (11.4836, 17.7277) and (11.5727, 17.8168) .. (11.5727, 17.9270) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (13.4879,19.0328) .. controls
    (13.4879, 19.1430) and (13.3988, 19.2320) .. (13.2887, 19.2320) .. controls
    (13.1789, 19.2320) and (13.0895, 19.1430) .. (13.0895, 19.0328) .. controls
    (13.0895, 18.9227) and (13.1789, 18.8336) .. (13.2887, 18.8336) .. controls
    (13.3988, 18.8336) and (13.4879, 18.9227) .. (13.4879, 19.0328) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (14.5938,20.9484) .. controls
    (14.5938, 21.0582) and (14.5047, 21.1477) .. (14.3945, 21.1477) .. controls
    (14.2848, 21.1477) and (14.1953, 21.0582) .. (14.1953, 20.9484) .. controls
    (14.1953, 20.8383) and (14.2848, 20.7488) .. (14.3945, 20.7488) .. controls
    (14.5047, 20.7488) and (14.5938, 20.8383) .. (14.5938, 20.9484) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (14.5938,23.1598) .. controls
    (14.5938, 23.2699) and (14.5047, 23.3594) .. (14.3945, 23.3594) .. controls
    (14.2848, 23.3594) and (14.1953, 23.2699) .. (14.1953, 23.1598) .. controls
    (14.1953, 23.0500) and (14.2848, 22.9605) .. (14.3945, 22.9605) .. controls
    (14.5047, 22.9605) and (14.5938, 23.0500) .. (14.5938, 23.1598) -- cycle;



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,nonzero rule] (13.4879,25.0754) .. controls
    (13.4879, 25.1855) and (13.3988, 25.2746) .. (13.2887, 25.2746) .. controls
    (13.1789, 25.2746) and (13.0895, 25.1855) .. (13.0895, 25.0754) .. controls
    (13.0895, 24.9652) and (13.1789, 24.8762) .. (13.2887, 24.8762) .. controls
    (13.3988, 24.8762) and (13.4879, 24.9652) .. (13.4879, 25.0754) -- cycle;



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (11.3734,43.8188) --
    (16.2953,41.9180);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (11.3734,43.8188) --
    (8.0613,39.7117);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (9.1617,43.8188) --
    (12.4738,39.7117);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (9.1617,43.8188) --
    (4.2398,41.9180);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (7.2465,44.9246) --
    (8.0613,39.7117);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (7.2465,44.9246) --
    (2.0332,45.7395);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (6.1406,46.8402) --
    (4.2398,41.9180);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (6.1406,46.8402) --
    (2.0332,50.1523);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (6.1406,49.0516) --
    (2.0332,45.7395);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (6.1406,49.0516) --
    (4.2398,53.9738);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (7.2465,50.9672) --
    (2.0332,50.1523);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (7.2465,50.9672) --
    (8.0613,56.1801);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (9.1617,52.0730) --
    (4.2398,53.9738);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (9.1617,52.0730) --
    (12.4738,56.1801);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (11.3734,52.0730) --
    (8.0613,56.1801);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (11.3734,52.0730) --
    (16.2953,53.9738);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (13.2887,50.9672) --
    (12.4738,56.1801);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (13.2887,50.9672) --
    (18.5020,50.1523);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (14.3945,49.0516) --
    (16.2953,53.9738);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (14.3945,49.0516) --
    (18.5020,45.7395);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (14.3945,46.8402) --
    (18.5020,50.1523);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (14.3945,46.8402) --
    (16.2953,41.9180);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (13.2887,44.9246) --
    (18.5020,45.7395);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=10.00] (13.2887,44.9246) --
    (12.4738,39.7117);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (9.1180,46.7254) --
    (11.3727,46.7465) -- (11.3727,48.9594) -- (9.1281,48.9594) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    1.33333,0.0124028,0.0124028,-1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (9.4016,46.6395) .. controls (9.4019, 46.5426) and (9.3230, 46.4641) ..
    (9.2262, 46.4642) .. controls (9.1289, 46.4639) and (9.0503, 46.5428) ..
    (9.0505, 46.6396) .. controls (9.0502, 46.7365) and (9.1310, 46.8155) ..
    (9.2259, 46.8154) .. controls (9.3232, 46.8152) and (9.4018, 46.7368) ..
    (9.4016, 46.6395) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    1.32099,1.33333,1.33333,-1.32099,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (11.7387,35.1340) .. controls (11.7388, 35.0649) and (11.6828, 35.0090) ..
    (11.6138, 35.0090) .. controls (11.5449, 35.0091) and (11.4892, 35.0649) ..
    (11.4890, 35.1338) .. controls (11.4891, 35.2026) and (11.5464, 35.2587) ..
    (11.6139, 35.2588) .. controls (11.6828, 35.2586) and (11.7387, 35.2027) ..
    (11.7387, 35.1340) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    -1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (1.4176,22.3340) .. controls (1.4176, 22.2656) and (1.3619, 22.2100) ..
    (1.2934, 22.2098) .. controls (1.2248, 22.2100) and (1.1691, 22.2656) ..
    (1.1691, 22.3340) .. controls (1.1691, 22.4027) and (1.2264, 22.4584) ..
    (1.2934, 22.4582) .. controls (1.3619, 22.4584) and (1.4176, 22.4027) ..
    (1.4176, 22.3340) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    -1.33333,-1.32709,-1.32709,1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (-11.4408,32.5517) .. controls (-11.4404, 32.4829) and (-11.4963, 32.4272) ..
    (-11.5652, 32.4270) .. controls (-11.6339, 32.4271) and (-11.6896, 32.4829) ..
    (-11.6896, 32.5517) .. controls (-11.6896, 32.6204) and (-11.6323, 32.6763) ..
    (-11.5652, 32.6763) .. controls (-11.4965, 32.6762) and (-11.4408, 32.6204) ..
    (-11.4408, 32.5517) -- cycle;



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (21.4457,46.8461) --
    (23.7004,46.8672) -- (23.6586,49.0590) -- (21.4563,49.0801) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    1.33333,0.0124034,0.0124034,-1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (21.7298,46.6455) .. controls (21.7297, 46.5486) and (21.6508, 46.4701) ..
    (21.5540, 46.4698) .. controls (21.4571, 46.4699) and (21.3781, 46.5488) ..
    (21.3783, 46.6457) .. controls (21.3784, 46.7425) and (21.4592, 46.8215) ..
    (21.5541, 46.8214) .. controls (21.6510, 46.8212) and (21.7295, 46.7428) ..
    (21.7298, 46.6455) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    1.29594,1.33333,1.33333,-1.29594,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (18.0739,28.7440) .. controls (18.0737, 28.6743) and (18.0174, 28.6181) ..
    (17.9477, 28.6179) .. controls (17.8782, 28.6179) and (17.8217, 28.6743) ..
    (17.8217, 28.7438) .. controls (17.8217, 28.8134) and (17.8796, 28.8700) ..
    (17.9477, 28.8698) .. controls (18.0173, 28.8698) and (18.0739, 28.8136) ..
    (18.0739, 28.7440) -- cycle;



  \path[cm={
    -1.33333,1.32058,1.32058,1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (-4.7888,16.0742) .. controls (-4.7890, 16.0053) and (-4.8450, 15.9494) ..
    (-4.9137, 15.9494) .. controls (-4.9827, 15.9493) and (-5.0386, 16.0053) ..
    (-5.0385, 16.0742) .. controls (-5.0387, 16.1431) and (-4.9811, 16.1989) ..
    (-4.9136, 16.1990) .. controls (-4.8449, 16.1991) and (-4.7889, 16.1433) ..
    (-4.7888, 16.0742) -- cycle;



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (9.1387,43.8414) --
    (9.1180,46.7359) -- (6.1500,46.8094);



  \path[cm={
    -1.33333,-1.31451,-1.31451,1.33333,(0.0,35.00000000000001)},draw=black,fill=black,even
    odd rule,line cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00]
    (-17.7947,38.5868) .. controls (-17.7948, 38.5178) and (-17.8508, 38.4617) ..
    (-17.9199, 38.4618) .. controls (-17.9889, 38.4619) and (-18.0450, 38.5180) ..
    (-18.0451, 38.5868) .. controls (-18.0450, 38.6558) and (-17.9874, 38.7119) ..
    (-17.9199, 38.7122) .. controls (-17.8509, 38.7121) and (-17.7948, 38.6560) ..
    (-17.7947, 38.5868) -- cycle;



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,fill=c800000,nonzero rule,line
    cap=butt,line join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (9.1590,46.7266)
    -- (13.2398,45.0254);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (11.3609,46.7477) --
    (11.3609,43.7965);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (11.3758,46.7922) --
    (14.3125,46.8367);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (11.4352,46.8367) --
    (13.3039,51.0043);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (14.3719,49.0465) --
    (11.3609,49.0020) -- (11.3461,52.0723);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (11.3906,48.9727) --
    (7.3566,50.9301);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (9.1398,52.0426) --
    (9.1074,49.0168) -- (6.1109,49.0168);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (9.1809,49.0168) --
    (7.2973,44.9383);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (18.5879,45.8027) --
    (21.4824,46.9352) -- (16.2805,53.9828);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (21.4465,46.8664) .. controls
    (20.6758, 39.9840) and (18.1570, 39.8863) .. (12.4586, 39.6883);



  \path[scale=1.33333,fill=black,even odd rule] (16.3750,27.9266) .. controls
    (16.2746, 27.8805) and (16.1563, 27.9246) .. (16.1102, 28.0246) .. controls
    (16.0641, 28.1250) and (16.1078, 28.2434) .. (16.2078, 28.2898) .. controls
    (16.3078, 28.3363) and (16.4266, 28.2930) .. (16.4730, 28.1930) .. controls
    (16.5195, 28.0930) and (16.4766, 27.9742) .. (16.3770, 27.9273);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (18.4504,50.1590) --
    (21.4762,49.0020) .. controls (21.3684, 54.9508) and (17.7195, 54.5066) ..
    (12.5773, 56.0914);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (21.5648,49.0613) .. controls
    (24.3945, 60.5082) and (8.6926, 61.1750) .. (4.2719, 53.9262);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (23.7008,49.0613) .. controls
    (21.4949, 57.8918) and (17.2074, 57.9723) .. (8.0391, 56.1508);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (23.6742,49.0613) .. controls
    (25.8547, 63.7418) and (1.6000, 64.8309) .. (2.0469, 50.1590);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (23.6414,49.0910) .. controls
    (26.5797, 41.1613) and (23.3746, 37.6852) .. (18.4270, 36.2148) .. controls
    (12.5898, 34.4797) and (3.6359, 36.3609) .. (4.3016, 41.8535);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (16.2852,41.8535) --
    (23.7305,46.8664) .. controls (19.4766, 37.2793) and (14.1152, 35.4027) ..
    (8.1277, 39.6586);



  \path[xscale=1.33333,yscale=-1.33333,draw=black,line cap=butt,line
    join=miter,line width=0.103cm,miter limit=4.00] (23.7313,46.8660) .. controls
    (23.6043, 38.9992) and (17.0289, 35.8336) .. (11.1586, 36.4934) .. controls
    (6.1871, 37.0520) and (1.7215, 40.3535) .. (2.1055, 45.8664);




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The tikz codes gives me:

[image]

**Eidt:** When I set `\def \globalscale {0.1}`, I see this graph, but it is not well.

[image]

Comment: `\path` only defines a path, it doesn't draw it. Replace all `\path` commands by `\draw`. Then you could simplify a bit those very precise coordinates, for example.

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks. But it does not work when I replace all `\path` commands by`\draw`.

Comment: @SebGlav Well. When I scaled it down (set `\def \globalscale {0.1}`)  I see this image, but it doesn't quite capture the original image well. Perhaps this is an issue with Inkscape.

Comment: @licheng, you can try a different route: a) save your drawing as pdf, e.g. via Inkscape, b) import it e.g. via package `pdfpages` . See e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39440/how-to-include-a-pdf-image-into-a-pdflatex-document or here https://www.baeldung.com/cs/latex-insert-pages-from-pdf. // You can also save it as bitmap, and just us `\includgraphics` from package `graphicx`, see e.g. here: https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf .//pdf is scaleable (unless you create a pdf-bitmap), while bitmaps are pixels.//SVG and Tikz aren't always "in love"

Comment: Replacing `\path` by `\draw` is useless here, because you got the `draw=black` inside the brackets. Your import is too complex, it seems that each vertex is drawn as a Bezier curve. If you just want to insert it as it is, better go for the `\includegraphics` solution. If you want to add informations on it, I think that you should start from scratch. It couls be time consuming but not hard to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, you can use something like the following (I let some work to be done, but it's not that hard to achieve).

[image: pretty complex graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        bezier bounding box, % To avoid blank space around your graph caused by bezier curves
        vtx/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}]
        
        \newcommand{\ra}{1} % radius for the inner square
        
        % Inner square
        \foreach \ang [count=\i from 0] in {45,135,225,315}
            \node[vtx] (inner-\i) at (\ang:\ra) {};
        \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i+1,4)}
            \draw (inner-\i) -- (inner-\j);
            }
        
        % Right square
        \foreach \ang [count=\i from 0] in {45,135,225,315}
            \path (7*\ra,0) --++ (\ang:\ra) node[vtx] (right-\i)  {};
        \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i+1,4)}
            \draw (right-\i) -- (right-\j);
            }       
        
        % Medium dodecahedron
        \foreach \ang [count=\i from 0] in {15,45,...,345}
            \node[vtx] (med-\i) at (\ang:2*\ra) {};
        \foreach \i in {0,...,11}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i+1,12)}
            \draw (med-\i) -- (med-\j);
            }
            
        % Outer dodecahedron
        \foreach \ang [count=\i from 0] in {15,45,...,345}
            \node[vtx] (outer-\i) at (\ang:4*\ra) {};
        \foreach \i in {0,...,11}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i+1,12)}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{mod(\i-1,12)}
            \ifnum\k<0 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{11} \fi
            \draw (outer-\i) -- (outer-\j);
            \draw (outer-\i) -- (med-\j);
            \draw (outer-\i) -- (med-\k);
            }
        
        % Some bended edges
        \draw (outer-2) to[out=0,in=100] (right-1);
        \draw (outer-3) to[out=45,in=120] (right-0);
        \draw (outer-5) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.5] (right-0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```